# render rdlc to PDF but with n Columns

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to render reports to HTML, but I don't find the way, so my second change is to render to PDF, but I have this issue,.. my reports have many columns and they are dynamic generated (matrix) , like a excel's pivot table, so they don't fit on a page.
The question is: It is posible to change the orientation of the generated pages from vertical to horizontal and even changes the page size ? I need that to avoid the cut of columns in different pages, it is posible?

thanks in advance

Comment: RDLC reports has built-in support for export to PDF. What's the problem using the feature?

Comment: Hi 
The problem is that as my report is very wide not enter a letter-sized page, and cuts on many pages, but I need this always on a page, do not want me to cut the columns as separate pages. That's way I want to create my own size page